# How to use Flush with GET method page

Tags: php, post, get, request, flush

I try to use flush in the target page of form submit to PHP page, but it not working.
I founded if the page has REQUEST ( GET or POST ) flush function will not be working.

Ex: http://example.com/receive.php <-- flush will work.

If I use: http://example.com/receive.php?a=111 <--- flush will not be working.

I use sample code below:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
ob_end_flush();
ob_implicit_flush();

for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    echo $i.'<br>';
    sleep(1);
}
```

- So, if you know, how to make flush work with page has REQUEST please help me. Thank you!